# Using LIKE with $wpdb->prepare

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm having trouble creating a SQL statement that includes a LIKE clause. As an example, let's say I want something like this.

select * from mytable where mycolumn like '%abc%'.

I want to run this through $wpdb->prepare so use this code.

```
$search = "abc";
$sql = "select * from mytable where mycolumn like '%%%s%%'";
$wpdb->prepare($sql, $search);
```

I've been researching this and have uncovered ways that folks SAY they address this (I have found accepted answers for each of these approaches, though some were old threads).

DOUBLE PERCENT SIGNS (to escape the literal)
As above.

SQUARE BRACKETS
Something like "select * from mytable where mycolumn like '[%]%s[%]'";

USING A VARIABLE

```
$likeClause = "%" . $search . "%";
$sql = "select * from mytable where mycolumn like '" . $likeClause . "'";
```

USING ESC_LIKE
Using something like this also has no effect.

```
$likeQuery = $wpdb->esc_like("%" . $search . "%");
```

All of these "fail", producing something like the following.

select * from mytable where mycolumn like '{c60f3895842b3abdcacc7948e0d2a1fe0152a8d9bbba77cdbb21340655b49548}ABC{c60f3895842b3abdcacc7948e0d2a1fe0152a8d9bbba77cdbb21340655b49548}'

Obviously none of these approaches are escaping the % symbol I need in the statement. Can someone please put me out of my misery?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8825/how-do-you-properly-prepare-a-like-sql-statement https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/esc_like/

Comment: Shoot - I knew I forgot something :) I have tried esc_like too, with no luck. For example, this doesn't escape the percentages. $likeQuery = $wpdb->esc_like("%" . $search) . "%");

Comment: I should add that if I print $likeQuery in the previous comment, I see that it shows "\%<my search text>\%". So it appears that $wpdb_esc_like is doing it's job, but when I pass that to $wpdb->prepare I still get the weird result in the opening post.

Comment: I updated the opening post to mention that I have also tried esc_like.